# Does .NET 6 have an ObjectPool class so I can pool my SFtpClient's?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-6.0, .net-7.0, object-pooling

I'm trying to find any code examples/docs about ObjectPooling in .NET 6.

I can see this [exists in .NET 7 via these docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/objectpool?view=aspnetcore-7.0), but I'm unable to upgrade to .NET 7.

I did find -some- code somewhere (No I can't see where. It was on my work computer, not this one at home) that looked something like this:

```
using System.Buffers;

var sftpObjectPool = new ObjectPool<SftpClient>(() => new SftpClient(config), 50);

var sftpClient = sftpObjectPool.Get();

await sftpClient.UploadFileAsync(..);

sftpObjectPool.Return(sftpClient);
```

but I've not been able to find this class in the .NET BCL.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`ObjectPool<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.objectpool.objectpool-1?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0) referenced in the docs is part of [`Microsoft.Extensions.ObjectPool`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.ObjectPool/8.0.0-preview.1.23112.2) package and is available for quite some time. It comes as dependency for ASP.NET Core (at least for 7th version), but for other projects types not based on `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web` you potentially will need to install it manually.

Based on the usage some other class was used in your app though.

With the `ObjectPool<T>` from the package something similar can look like:

```cs
var objectPool = new DefaultObjectPool<SftpClient>(
    FactoryPolicy.Create(() => new SftpClient(config)), 
    maximumRetained: 50);

class FactoryPolicy<T> : PooledObjectPolicy<T> where T : notnull
{
    private readonly Func<T> _factory;

    public FactoryPolicy(Func<T> factory)
    {
        _factory = factory;
    }

    public override T Create() => _factory();

    public override bool Return(T obj) => true;
}

class FactoryPolicy
{
    public static IPooledObjectPolicy<T> Create<T>(Func<T> factory) where T : notnull 
        => new FactoryPolicy<T>(factory);
}
```

Comment: Ah! so I've actually got a `class library` .. which means I'll need to add this dependency! And was that code (above) more or less right, also?

Comment: @Pure.Krome no, it seems that was some other class.